# Combining SQL statements into one insert with case conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've figured out the logic I need to create a derived table from one of my other tables on this database. But I am not sure how to correctly combine the statements for the desired effect. Basically I am moving over 3 columns on some criteria and the 4th column I am parsing into two columns on the derived table.

I'm trying to resolve the logic to get this query working but I am a bit lost on how to structure it.

```
INSERT INTO table (Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5)
SELECT
r.col1,
r.col2,
r.col3,

(case 
when FirstBackslashPos > 0 and FirstUnderscorePos > 0
then substring(ParseValue,FirstBackslashPos+1,FirstUnderscorePos-FirstBackslashPos-1) 
end ) as Col4,

(case 
when FirstUnderscorePos > 0 and SecondBackslashPos > 0 
then substring(ParseValue,FirstUnderscorePos+1,SecondBackslashPos-FirstUnderscorePos-1) 
end) as Col5

FROM (
  select 
   r.ThisValue as ParseValue, 
  charindex('\',ThisValue ) as FirstBackslashPos,
  charindex('_',ThisValue  , charindex('_',ThisValue)+1) asFirstUnderscorePos,
  charindex('\',ThisValue,charindex('\',ThisValue)+1) as SecondBackslashPos
from sometable r Where somecolumn1 = 'SomeValue%')

GO
```

Everything comes from the same table I am deriving the data for this one from. Just not sure how to structure it so the charindexes can be found by by sub-case statements.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Do you mean you want to avoid the inline view (subquery) and embed the charindex calls directly in the `case` expressions?  You can do that with simple cut-n-paste, but you will end up repeating the same charindex call multiple times. If you do want to reuse the charindex results, your current query is a reasonable way to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CROSS APPLY` to execute the same functions to all rows of the dataset and have the result available in the usual areas of the statement.

```
INSERT INTO table (Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5)

SELECT
    r.col1,
    r.col2,
    r.col3,

    case 
        when ca.FirstBackslashPos > 0 and ca.FirstUnderscorePos > 0
        then substring(r.ThisValue,ca.FirstBackslashPos+1,ca.FirstUnderscorePos-ca.FirstBackslashPos-1) 
    end as Col4,

    case 
        when ca.FirstUnderscorePos > 0 and ca.SecondBackslashPos > 0 
        then substring(r.ThisValue,ca.FirstUnderscorePos+1,ca.SecondBackslashPos-ca.FirstUnderscorePos-1) 
    end as Col5

FROM sometable r

CROSS APPLY (
    select 
        charindex('\',r.ThisValue ) as FirstBackslashPos,
        charindex('_',r.ThisValue,charindex('_',r.ThisValue)+1) as FirstUnderscorePos,
        charindex('\',r.ThisValue,charindex('\',r.ThisValue)+1) as SecondBackslashPos
    ) ca

WHERE r.somecolumn1 = 'SomeValue%';

GO
```

Answer (score 0):

You were very close, the way you were calculating FirstUnderscorePos was wrong.

Using this sample data:

```
USE tempdb
Go

CREATE TABLE dbo.SomeTable (ThisValue varchar(1000));
INSERT dbo.SomeTable
VALUES ('fistRecord\1st_monkey\xxx'), ('second\2_xxx\zzz'), ('fruit\orange_orange\apple');
```

Your query should look like this (I'm just using dummy values for col1, col2 and col3):

```
SELECT col1 = 'xxx', col2 = 'xxx', col3 = 'xxx', --ParseValue,
case 
when FirstBackslashPos > 0 and FirstUnderscorePos > 0
then substring(ParseValue,FirstBackslashPos+1,FirstUnderscorePos FirstBackslashPos-1) 
end 
as Col4
case 
when FirstUnderscorePos > 0 and SecondBackslashPos > 0 
then substring(ParseValue,FirstUnderscorePos+1,SecondBackslashPos-    FirstUnderscorePos-1) 
end as Col5
FROM 
(
  select 
     r.ThisValue as ParseValue, 
     charindex('\',ThisValue ) as FirstBackslashPos,
     charindex('_',ThisValue ) as FirstUnderscorePos,
     charindex('\',ThisValue,charindex('\',ThisValue)+1) as SecondBackslashPos
  from dbo.SomeTable r 
) x;
```